# Problem with my assembly files of XR and ARFoundation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, ar-foundation

I was working with Unity XR and everything worked fine, but at some point i needed to change the AR Session Origin tag and so i did, but after this, when i opened the scripts, i found red errors on everything that used the XR namespace:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Hdg.png)

The error says "The type or namespace of "ARFoundation" / "ARSubsystems" doesn't exist in the namespace "UnityEngine.XR". There are probably some Assembly references missing." (Sorry if it's not the exact same wording but i'm translating it in english from my language).

What do i have to do to fix this?

I did not change any assembly script, nor have i changed the script in any way before changing the game object's tag, so i don't know what is happening. I already tried to delete them and rewrite them, i tried to delete them and add them through Unity's suggestions

Comment: Did you perhaps update your XR package?

Comment: i didn't update anything unfortunately, otherwise it would have made "sense". But i did try to update it afterwards to maybe try to fix things

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "tag"? From what I can see the SessionOrigin is a prefab. Also the red squiggles point to the assemblies not being linked for some reason. Are the console errors sth like "...xxx assembly does not exist..."?

Comment: Out of curiosity, in older versions, whenever Unity behaved weirdly, deleting Library and reimporting would sometimes help (I guess in this case even reimporting the packages involved could work). Have you tried anything of the sort?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it: it was an error on Unity's end that for some reason messed up the assembly scripts, when i opened a copy of the project i made to test some fixes i found out that copying, pasting and using the copied version allowed unity to re-build the assembly files and fix itself